# Posting comment to YouTube with GData ObjC client library fails

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-api, youtube-api

I'm trying to implement commenting on YouTube videos with the [gdata-objectivec-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client) library, using the code snippet posted in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gdata-objectivec-client/a2mln6iQyK0/BjapQOLrBbIJ); copy follows:

```
- (void)addCommentTitle:(NSString *)commentTitle
            text:(NSString *)commentContent
            toVideo:(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry {
    GDataComment *commentObj = [entry comment];
    GDataFeedLink *feedLink = [commentObj feedLink];
    NSURL *feedURL = [feedLink URL];
    if (feedURL) {
        // fetch the comment feed for the video
        GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
        [service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                completionHandler:^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *commentFeed, NSError *error) {
                    // callback
                    //
                    // insert a new comment into the comment feed
                    if (error == nil) {
                        GDataEntryYouTubeComment *newCommentEntry = [GDataEntryYouTubeComment commentEntry];
                        [newCommentEntry setTitleWithString:commentTitle];
                        [newCommentEntry setContentWithString:commentContent];

                        NSURL *postURL = [[commentFeed postLink] URL];
                        [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:newCommentEntry
                                                 forFeedURL:postURL
                                          completionHandler:^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataEntryBase *entry, NSError *error) {
                                              // callback
                                              if (error == nil) {
                                                  // succeeded
                                              }
                                          }];
                    }
                }];
        }
    }
```

but I always get the following exception:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[GDataObject setContentStringValue:](), XXXXXXXX/GData/BaseClasses/GDataObject.m:2353
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'GDataEntryYouTubeComment setting undeclared content value'
```

Luckily enough, I managed to make this go away by adding a new call before the comment contents are set:

```
GDataEntryYouTubeComment* newCommentEntry = [GDataEntryYouTubeComment commentEntry];
[newCommentEntry addContentValueDeclaration];    // <--- this method does the trick
[newCommentEntry setTitleWithString:commentTitle];
[newCommentEntry setContentStringValue:commentContent];
```

but it's still not OK as the request now bounces back from the server with this error:

```
serviceBase:<GDataServiceGoogleYouTube: 0x7a73eb0>
objectFetcher:GTMHTTPFetcher 0x7c75b20 (https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/XXXXXXXXXX/comments)
failedWithStatus:400
data:<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ParseException</code><internalReason>[Line 2, Column 514, element entry] No converter for type class java.lang.Void</internalReason></error><error><domain>GData</domain><code>missingConverter</code><internalReason>No converter for type class java.lang.Void</internalReason></error></errors>
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is this an error on my side or Google's side?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the above code is correct, in my code I misspelled

```
[newCommentEntry setContentWithString:commentContent];
```

and used

```
[newCommentEntry setContentStringValue:commentContent];
```

instead. Now it works fine.